# mschart column graph SideBySide Mode off, Bringing beneath columns to front

Tags: c#, layout, mschart

```
Random random = new Random();   
for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
{
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(10);
chart1.Series[1].Points.AddY(30);
chart1.Series[2].Points.AddY(50);
}

chart1.Series[0]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
chart1.Series[1]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
chart1.Series[2]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
```

Please View this as I am getting thing result.
[Image of MSCHART](http://imgh.us/Untitled_255.png)

As you can sea Series1 and Series2 is not being displayed.
My Question is
How to sort columns on the base of points. i.e, how to bring series 1 columns in front, series 2 after series 1 and series 3 at last.
Thankx in advance.

Chart type is column

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the image link is dead, the question is no longer clear.

Answer (score 0):

The series will be drawn in the order you added them to the chart. So series[2] will be drawn last, over the other two.